# How is boundedness almost everywhere defined?

Tags: real-analysis

An exercise in a book I am using supposes a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies $f < \infty$ almost everywhere. For each $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)$ is real-valued and finite, so I believe the only reasonable way to interpret the statement is "boundedness almost everywhere". I'm not sure how we define this, since a function is bounded on a set, not at a point. So far, the book has not discussed the extended real line at all, so I don't think the function can take on the values $\pm\infty$, but the wording of the exercise is ambiguous.

Should I take this to mean that there is a restriction of $f$ to a set $F$ such that $m(R - F) = 0$ and $f$ is bounded on $F$?

Edit: The book is Real Analysis for Graduate Students (bass.math.uconn.edu/v42.pdf) exercise 6.1 on pg. 55.

Comment: To get a useful answer, you need to give a precise statement of the text in the book and/or a reference to the book.

Comment: @RobArthan The book is Real Analysis for Graduate Students (http://bass.math.uconn.edu/v42.pdf) exercise 6.1.

Comment: It means it is bounded everywhere except possibly on a set of measure $0$. Be careful about what this means though. Consider the function $f=\frac{1}{x}$ on $(0,1)$. For any $x$ the output is finite, but the function is not bounded on the interval as $\nexists C\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $|f|\le C$ for all $x\in(0,1)$. So your function cannot "go to infinity" anywhere but there could be isolated points where it is defined to be infinity (if you were working on the extended real line).